# How to optimize Less code using the -O2 option

Tags: css, node.js, shell, less

I [found this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10965495/1420197) about how to compile the less files, optimizing (`-O2`) and compressing (`-x`) them:

```
lessc -x -O2 path/to/assets/main.less > path/to/output.css
```

I installed `less` globally (`npm install -g less`), but it seems that `-O2` is not interpreted like expected:

> `Unable to interpret argument O2 - if it is a plugin (less-plugin-O2), make sure that it is installed under or at the same level as less`

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Is that a zero, `0`, or an upper-case letter, `O`?

Comment: @Sparky It's letter, `O`...

Comment: That seems to be a very old answer mate and Less has undergone a lot of revisions post it, so I doubt if that particular option got dropped (or) was replaced.

Comment: @Harry I also think that it was deprecated, but finding the replacement for that would be great.

Comment: @IonicăBizău: Yup trying mate. The comment by Zack (to shakaran's answer) in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691173/how-do-i-compile-a-directory-full-of-less-css-files-to-css) thread kind of confirms the assumption that it was deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What exactly do you expect from that `-02` option? It is not available in the latest versions of Less any more.

From Less v1.5:

> -------------------------- Deprecated ----------------
>     -O0, -O1, -O2            Set the parser's optimization level. The lower
>                              the number, the less nodes it will create in the
>                              tree. This could matter for debugging, or if you
>                              want to access the individual nodes in the tree.

-

> I expect that if I do: h1 { font-weight: 300; } h2 { font-weight: 300; }, then, after 
>   compilation, I have: h1, h2 { font-weight: 300; }. That's why I understood that -O2 was 
>   doing. Is there any replacement for that?

I wonder if -O2 indeed did that. But clean-css does what you are asking.

You could try https://github.com/less/less-plugin-clean-css with the `advanced` option turned on.

Run `npm install less-plugin-clean-css` after that you can use `lessc file.less --clean-css="advanced"`.

```
echo "h1 { font-weight: 300; } h2 { font-weight: 300; }" | lessc --clean-css="advanced" -
```

outputs into the console:

```
h1,h2{font-weight:300}
```

See also: [How to keep duplicate properties in compiled CSS file when use LESS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27544448/how-to-keep-duplicate-properties-in-compiled-css-file-when-use-less/27612169)

Since version 2 of Less writing your own plugin is easy, see: http://lesscss.org/usage/#plugins-for-plugin-authors. You can write a plugin for any postprocess such compressing, minifying and so on, other examples: https://github.com/less/less-plugin-autoprefix, https://github.com/bassjobsen/less-plugin-pleeease.

Comment: I expect that if I do: `h1 { font-weight: 300; } h2 { font-weight: 300; }`, then, after compilation, I have: `h1, h2 { font-weight: 300; }`. That's why I understood that `-O2` was doing. Is there any replacement for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can install older version

```
npm install less@1.5 -g
```

It is solution for using in Eclipse 4.4.2 fo r Windows.

Comment: `O` option had no effect a while before `1.5` (Actually I doubt it ever had any effect since the very first JS version. Most likely this was just an overlooked left-over from the original Ruby version (and even there it was just about internal AST representation not affecting the generated CSS in any way)).